# R markdown color working one machine but not another

Tags: r, r-markdown, pdflatex

Hi I'm running R studio on windows trying to generate a table in Markdown using kableExtra.  Recently I notice that colors are working on one of my machine and not another.

```
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
library(Vennerable)


kable(cars, format = "latex", booktabs = T, caption = "Demo Table") %>%
  kable_styling(full_width = F)  %>%
  column_spec(1:1, italic = T, color = "black", background = "yellow") %>%
  column_spec(2, bold = T, border_right = T, background = "SpringGreen")
```

so this runs flawless on one of my pc but in another it give this error.

```
! Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `SpringGreen'.
```

I'm not sure of any particular reason why this is so.  Anyone have a clue? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just added HTML hex color code support to the dev version of kableExtra. If you are willing to use the dev ver, you can do things like.

```
kable(cars, format = "latex", booktabs = T, caption = "Demo Table") %>%
  kable_styling(full_width = F)  %>%
  column_spec(1:1, italic = T, color = "black", background = "yellow") %>%
  column_spec(2, bold = T, border_right = T, background = "#00FF7F")
```

(I found the hex code for `springgreen` from http://latexcolor.com/)

Comment: wow great thank you... being able to use hex codes will make it much more flexible.

Comment: Yep, in fact, you can use hex codes in `color` in current CRAN ver. It's just that I forgot to extend it to `background` last time. :P