# Using hex code to change text color in RMarkdown PDF (R)

Tags: r, hex

I'm trying to change the text color in an RMD file using a PDF output. I'm doing this for work and need to use a specific hex color code.

I was able to successfully change the text color using the command:

```
Roses are \textcolor{red}{red}, violets are \textcolor{blue}{blue}
```

Is it possible to change the text color in a PDF output using color hex codes?
Example:

```
Roses are \textcolor{#1C8FCE}{#1C8FCE}, violets are \textcolor{#BBD531}{#BBD531}
```

Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can, see [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59859012/render-a-hexcolor-inline-in-an-r-markdown-file) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47206399/r-markdown-color-working-one-machine-but-not-another):

You can also use [CSS](https://www.garrickadenbuie.com/blog/r-colors-css/?panelset=css):

e.g.:

````
```{css echo=FALSE}
.my color {
  color: #FF0000;
  font-weight: 700
}
```


#R Markdown
`r sprintf("<span class='my color'>BLAH-BLAH</span>")`
````

To make a pdf from html. `"Knit to Html" - > "Open in Browser" -> "Save as PDF..."`

Comment: Does this really work for you? I cannot reproduce this, i.e. the color does not change in the **pdf**.

Comment: @tpetzoldt Yes, wait, i add a pic

Comment: I can reproduce it only for html, not pdf.

Comment: @tpetzoldt Agree, but we can easily make a pdf from html.
```"Knit to Html" - > "Open in Browser" -> "Save as PDF..."```
But i agree, that in the "Knit to PDF" straightaway doesn't work, sry.

Comment: @tpetzoldt because ```PDF requires TEX (MiKTeX on Windows)```, as written in Options. If someone wants to make PDF document in TEX-style, yes, your solution is preferable.

Answer (score 2):

It is easy in html, where you can just use `<span>`. In PDF, one can first define custom colors in a latex preamble and then use this in the markdown text.

Create a file `preamble.tex` and put it at a suitable location, e.g. drive `d:` where we define custom colors:

```
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{myred}{HTML}{E05428}
\definecolor{myviolet}{HTML}{7653B5}
```

Then it can be used in a markdown document, e.g. file `test.Rmd`:

```
---
output:
  pdf_document:
      includes:
          in_header: "d:/preamble.tex"
---

Roses are \textcolor{myred}{red}, violets are \textcolor{myviolet}{violet}
```